# Heroku python NLP search background task

Tags: redis, worker

Hi I have a NLP spacy phrase matching task (in Python) on 100000 documents and return a list of matched document ids as result to the client to display. I have a RQ worker to perform search function as a background job. This is working perfectly on a standalone Machine but throwing H12 error when deployed to Heroku. The front end is very simple. It takes user query and waits to render the document ids. Please help

Comment: Can you please give an example? How does a doc my look or a key?

Comment: Thank you @GuyKorland. In my case a document is  a text file. All documents are indexed and I need to return the set of document ids to the client. It is working for some of the requests but throwing H12 error for long processes. I have one worker thread. I dont know how to run asynchronoously